# Why JIT (Just-In-Time) Debugger does not available in VS2019 Enterprise when it's running on Windows Server 2019 Standard?

Tags: visual-studio, iis, jit, windows-server-2019

Why JIT (Just-In-Time) Debugger does not available in VS2019 Enterprise when it's running on Windows Server 2019 Standard ?

Nothing in NT2019:

[image]

However, it's available in Win10:

[image]

Question: how to enable JIT for web pages in Windows NT2019?

Final goal: enable ASP (legacy ASP, version 3) debugging

VS2019 running with local Admin rights

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Actually it must be installed separately